# How to like a facebook page/follow a twitter user using social framework in iOS 6?

Tags: facebook, twitter, ios6, facebook-like, social-framework

Is there an easy way to like a facebook page/follow a twitter user using social framework in iOS 6?

I can post messages to the user's facebook/twitter account fine using the framework.

Answer (score 3):

This is a method for following a user on twitter

```
-(void)followTwitter{

ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"this is the request of account ");
     if (granted==YES) {
         NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
         if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
         {
             // Keep it simple, use the first account available
             ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

             NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"FollowedUserNameHere",@"screen_name",@"TRUE",@"follow", nil];
             TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"] parameters:dictionary requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

             [request setAccount:acct];

             [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
              {
                  if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200)
                  {
                      // The response from Twitter is in JSON format
                      // Move the response into a dictionary and print
                      NSError *error;
                      NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
                      NSLog(@"Twitter response: %@", dict);
                  }
                  else
                      NSLog(@"Twitter error, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
              }];
         }     
     }
 }];
```

}

and follow this link for liking facebook page

http://angelolloqui.blogspot.jp/2010/11/facebook-like-button-on-ios.html

Comment: Slight change, instead of TWRequest, you would now be using SLRequest.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that as of iOS 6.0 `TWRequest` was deprecated in favor of `SLRequest` from the Social framework, eg the accepted answer at: [Twitter SLRequest performRequestWithHandler - Could not prepare the URL request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945888/twitter-slrequest-performrequestwithhandler-could-not-prepare-the-url-request)